# Passing Variables Into Statement Block Brackets In PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have an array I want to pass into a variable which is then passed into a `Register-ObjectEvent`.

It looks like the following:

```
$body = @{
    project_id = $project_id
    task_token = $task_token
}

$action = {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost/temp.php -Method Post -Body $body}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier MyTimer -Action $action
```

I noticed in the above that the `$project_id` and `$task_token` variables are lost when placed between the `{}` when I am assigning the script block to `$action`.

How do I preserve the variables here?

Comment: In your script, do you define $project_id and $task_token previously in the code?  $body's value will be set as soon as the line $body is executed, so the values for those variables need to be set before $body.  In my testing, this works fine.

Comment: @FoxDeploy Yes, `$project_id` and `$task_token` are set, but not shown here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not supposed to work in the way you write it for at least two reasons.

**First** : I am not sure about this one, but when you write :

```
$body = @{
    project_id = $project_id
    task_token = $task_token
}
```

`$body` is a hashtable so are you sure it will constitute a good value for `-body` parameter ?

**Second** : The action script block is going to be executed in another job so `$body`  variable will not be available in the scope of the action block as writen in the [Register-ObjectEvent](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849929.aspx) documentation :"*The value of the Action parameter can include the $Event, $EventSubscriber, $Sender, $EventArgs, and $Args automatic variables, which provide information about the event to the Action script block. For more information, see about_Automatic_Variables.*".

So in your case, if you want to specifie additional data to be associated with this event subscription, you can use `-MessageData` parameter this way (here I don' take care of the **first** remark):

```
$action = {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri http://localhost/temp.php -Method Post -Body $($event.MessageData)"}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier MyTimer -Action $action -MessageData $body
```